# Any method to gracefully remove website visitors before maintenance?

Tags: e-commerce, maintenance-mode

Is there any way to gracefully remove visitors from a site rather than just putting the site into maintenance and booting everybody out? In particular I am thinking of an eCommerce site where there might be carts open, or even checkouts in progress, but I suppose this would apply to other sites.

Ideally I would envisage a system which would redirect new traffic to a maintenance page; but allow the site to "empty" over a period of time ... and have a monitor of number of visitors and whether they were active.

Does anything like this exist, or what is the industry standard workflow? I usually do maintenance in the middle of the night but that will only work to a certain degree, and not on an international site.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some maintenance on an eCommerce site yesterday and I used a sitewide notice ( which is available by default with many shopping cart systems; or could be easily achieved using some basic HTML/CSS if not ) .... I made it very prominent and put a clear start time for the maintenance on this notice ... also I started when I said I would.

In the absence of a more foolproof system this lo-fi approach seemed to work well – and maybe that's the best the industry can do at present. I'll leave this here as the answer unless someone comes up with something better.